# How can i use subdomain as website storage?

Tags: php, upload, webserver, subdomain, storage

I have a website (examplewebsite.com) which allows users to upload their personal photos & videos to their profile.

I would like to have an separate webserver (subdomain.examplewebsite.com) when a user uploads, the content will automatically store the photos and videos in their profile.

As the user wants to go back and view their content it can also be retrieved from the (subdomain.examplewebsite.com) server.

How can i do this using PHP? is this possible? 
This would be considered my storage server for the main website. (examplewebsite.com)

cannot find any info

Comment: It doesn‘t matter if you store the photo on physically the same or another server. At the end it‘s mainly a DNS Setup. Try to find infomation about „setup dns subdomain“

Comment: I guess the server hardware doesn't belong to you, but you have rented some webspace from a provider. Then your provider has to allow you to create and use subdomains, which usually are just pointing to a subdirectory on your webspace instead of the root directory. So it would still be on the same server, only in another directory. PHP itself has nothing to do with subdomains.

Comment: @HappyAnt Your guess is entirely wrong. Please remove your comment as this has absolue nothing to do with guesses. and the answer i was NOT looking for.